# Disable drag, pinch and twist ArFragment

Tags: java, android, arcore

Is possible to fix the dimensions and the place of the objects in ArCore on Android?
I want to disable the drag, pinch and twist options from the ArFragment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider using [TransformableNode](https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/java/sceneform/reference/com/google/ar/sceneform/ux/TransformableNode) and disable scaleController, rotationController and translationController:

```
val anchorNode = AnchorNode(anchor)
val node = TransformableNode(fragment.transformationSystem)
node.scaleController.isEnabled = false
node.rotationController.isEnabled = false
node.translationController.isEnabled = false
node.renderable = renderable
node.setParent(anchorNode)
fragment.arSceneView.scene.addChild(anchorNode)
```